# How to setup a Dapp developer fee?

Tags: dapp-development, fees

Is it possible and convenient to address a small fee to the Dev wallet when a smart contract between 2 counterparts has been cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to make a return from users of your smart contract, you could take a percentage from a transaction to the contract and sends it to another address. It gets a little weird with percents, because as far as I know (I'd love to hear otherwise) fixed point types are still in development.

You could write in a basic fee condition. Say you have a `payable` function in the contract that would otherwise only require gas to call. In Solidity, you could just call `msg.value` within the function to get the amount sent, and `throw` if the amount sent to the contract is less than the fee.

But even if you had something in your contract or Dapp that charged a fee, the contract is still viewable by anyone on the public blockchain. Meaning, with enough effort someone could reverse-engineer the contract and create a new one without the fee.